# How to solve Apple Mach-O Linker Error (MobileWifi framework)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried to use this project classes: https://github.com/Cykey/wifi/tree/master/src

But i didnt call any class, an i get a lot of linker error...

I uploaded a picture from my errors: http://oi59.tinypic.com/aaw5z7.jpg

Please help me!

Comment: I think That library is not supported to armv7 architecture

Comment: so how could i use this app on ipad 3?

Comment: your running in directly in device (The application is working in simulator ? and The application to build it is showing any error ? )

Comment: I cant run this application in simulator because i use for bluetooth another private api, and it cant run on simulator...
if i try to build my project i get the errors in my question

Comment: I am asking  application is running or not (functionality is working or not forgot about that). Once run the application in simulator are you getting any error

Comment: I cant run in simulator because the build fails my linker errors..